# Magento 2 filter with custom customer attribute in create order select customer grid

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2. In Admin -> Sales -> Order create order it is displaying all customer list. I want to filter that list with custom customer attribute. I already created attribute.

**Example :**

Customer Attribute : Allow to create order -> Yes / No

In create order customer list only those customer should display which attribute value is "Yes".

Comment: any feedback whether my solution works at your end David?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, we can separate the problem in 3 steps:

**step 1: create a customer attribute**

for this, you have done this job. But it is important to verify the customer can be persistently saved with the data: if you have any doubt whether this solution works for you, you might go in the backend, change the field value to true for a given customer and once it is successfully saved, go back and verify the field value is correct.

**step 2: we want to take over the resource model that feeds this grid in the backend**

create a new module and add the layout file `sales_order_create_customer_block.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="adminhtml.customer.grid.container">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="dataSource" xsi:type="object">Mbs\CustomerGridFilter\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

note: the location for this file is: `app/code/Mbs/CustomerGridFilter/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_customer_block.xml`

**step 3: take over the resource and add the filter**. In the code below, you may change it to use your customer attribute code

```
   <?php

namespace Mbs\CustomerGridFilter\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer;

use Mbs\CustomerGridFilter\Model\CustomerRule;

class Collection extends \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection
{
    /**
     * @return \Mbs\CompanyName\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Customer\Collection
     */
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        parent::_initSelect();

        $this->addFieldToFilter('show_in_create_order', 1);

        return $this;
    }
}
```